# how to determine the Enum type

Tags: swift, enums

I have a struct (is a SwiftUI - View in this case, but the question has nothing to do with SwiftUI because it could be any Struct) with a generic which should be an Enum - type.
Can i ask somehow the generic, what type the enum is?

example:

```
enum TestA : String {
    case a = "a"
    case b = "b"
}

var id : TestA
```

so i would like to have something like

```
if id.isKind(of:String)
```

as it works for classes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Whatever<EnumType>: View {

    let id: EnumType


    func askForType() {

        if id.isKind(of:String) {  <<<  this is not working, i know, but is there a workaround?
            print("is string")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

        Text("aha")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good work around but might need some more logic.

In SwiftUI,

```
enum TestA : Int {
    case a = 1
    case b = 2
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let id = TestA.self

    func askForType() -> String{
        return String(describing: type(of: id.RawValue))

    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(askForType())
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

[image]

What this does is print the demangled type of the enum. In the example, this prints `Int.rawvalue`. Removing `.rawValue` from the type will only print the Enum identifier rather than type.